# NSDate and string without timezone information

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, nsdate

I am parsing some XML that is returned by a web service. The string: `2015-12-24T12:00:00` is found in the `fromTimestamp` with no timezone. The "geniuses" (I don't mean that) keeps the timezone information in a own field in the XML in minutes. So `300` means GMT+05:00.

I have been reading a lot about `NSDate` and all this timezone stuff and I know that `NSDate` don't care about timezones, thats `NSDateFormatter` job.

However, in order to "convert" the timestamp without the timezone so that the value in NSDate represents a GMT time I add the `GMT+05:00` to the string so it becomes `2015-12-24T12:00:00 +05:00`. This is how it must be done right? Without adding the timezone when you convert from string to date the `NSDate` thinks the value is the GMT time? Thats the part I don't understand about it. It would be wrong to just convert the string without that timezone information because `NSDate` wouldn't be able to subtract 5 hours from the value inside `NSDate`? Is that correct? I am having a hard time explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assessment is correct and your solution is one of two possible solutions.

To ensure the date string is properly converted to an `NSDate`, you can do one of two things:

1. You need to ensure the date string has timezone information included and the date formatter's format string includes the proper format specifier for the timezone. This is what you describe in your question.
2. You leave the date string as you have it, without timezone information. But you set a specific timezone on the date formatter based on the timezone field you get from the XML.

Either approach will give you the proper `NSDate`.

Update: My second approach is shown in the answer by Martin R.

Comment: So my reasoning about the necessarity of adding the timezone information to the string before it is converted to a NSDate is correct? Because otherwise the timestamp would have been interpreted as GMT without subtracting some hours from it first? ( it is so hard to explain what I mean, hope you understand).

Comment: Close. If no specific timezone information is parsed from the date string and the date formatter has no specific timezone set, then the date string will be treated as "local" time, not GMT.

Comment: Does that mean that it use the timezone it gets from the system?

Comment: It means it uses the user's current timezone.

Comment: So if the users current timezone is +05:00, does that mean if you format that date with a formatter where the timezone is set to +01:00 it subtracts 4 hours from the time in the NSDate object?

Comment: No. If you set a specific timezone on the date formatter then the user's timezone is irrelevant.

Comment: But I mean if you pass the date formatted without any timezone to another formatter which has the timezone set to +01:00?

Comment: If you parse a date string that has no timezone info, and the date formatter's timezone is set to +01:00 then the date string will be assumed to be in the +01:00 timezone. That's the whole point of option two in my answer (and Martin's answer).

Comment: Yes, I understand. But if you have 2 formatters, the first one without any timezone set what so ever, and then another one with timezone.

Comment: They are independent. Once you have an `NSDate`, if you use a date formatter to convert it back to another string, it will be in whatever timezone is set on the date formatter (which defaults to the user's current timezone).

Answer (score 1):

It may be simpler to set the time zone of the date formatter
explicitly. Example (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
let fromTimestamp = "2015-12-24T12:00:00"
let timeZoneInfo = "300"

let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

let secondsFromGMT = Int(timeZoneInfo)! * 60
fmt.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: secondsFromGMT)

let date = fmt.dateFromString(fromTimestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it more convenient to wrap Martin's approach as an extension of the String class. It also prepends it with current timestamp and writes text ta a debugger output.

Swift 5:

```
"Hello world".log()
```

> 2019-09-05 12:18:10 Hello world

```
extension String {

    func log() {

        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"
        let formattedString = "\(fmt.string(from: Date())) \(self)"

        print(formattedString)

        let log = URL(fileURLWithPath: "log.txt")
        do {
            let handle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: log)
            handle.seekToEndOfFile()
            handle.write((formattedString+"\n").data(using: .utf8)!)
            handle.closeFile()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            do {
                try self.data(using: .utf8)?.write(to: log)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }        
    }    
}
```